# Recording an HTML canvas element to video with MediaRecorder results in a corrupted video and only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to record an animation in an HTML canvas element to a .webm video. However there are two issues with the code. Whenever I download the video after the code is done executing (without errors), the video is corrupted. Another issue is that the code doesn't work in Firefox. Only in Chrome.

What I'd like to achieve are 3 things.

1. I want a working video.
2. I'd like to also record audio to the video. (this functionality currently isn't in the code yet)
3. I'm wondering why this code doesn't work in Firefox, but does work in Chrome without errors and if maybe there's a way to make it work in all browser.

I'd like the resulting code to be as simple as possible. I'm trying to avoid complex solutions.

```
        var theCanvasElementToRecord = document.querySelector('#videoCanvas');            
        var stream = theCanvasElementToRecord.captureStream(25); 

        var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
        var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);            

        mediaRecorder.start();

        var recordedChunks = [];

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {

            recordedChunks.push(e.data);
            var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
                type: 'video/webm'
            });
            console.log(blob);

            var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);   

            var link = document.createElement("a"); 
            link.href = blobUrl;
            link.download = "video.webm";
            link.innerHTML = "Click here to download the file";
            document.body.appendChild(link); 

        }


        /* Canvas animation code */


        mediaRecorder.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `video/webm;codecs=vp9` codec is currently only supported on Blink.

You can check for support before by calling MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported

```js
console.log(
  MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(
    "video/webm;codecs=vp9"
  )
);
```

2. The `ondataavailable` callback will fire anytime some new chunk of data is available. This may happen quite often, and you may not have significant bits in there. That's why the code you copied from did initialize this `recordedChunks` array, that is correctly filled in this event. However, the final Blob export should only be done in the `mediaRecorder.onstop` event handler.
3. You are calling `stop()` synchronously right after having called `start()`. There must be some time to elapse so that there is actually something to get recorded. You will have to wrap this call in an asynchronous call, e.g `setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), 10000)` if you want to record for 10s.
4. You need to actually draw on your canvas after you initialized the stream, otherwise, the stream may stay muted, and the recorder won't have anything to record.